# Django Rlationships levels

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-2.0

I have 3 models : User, Attribute, Site.

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid =  models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    name=   models.BooleanField(null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('myapp:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userid

class Site(models.Model):
    pK_site =   models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    name =   models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pK_site

class Attribute(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role=   models.CharField(max_length=200)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.site)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('myapp:edit', kwargs={'pk' : self.userid.pk})
```

My problem is when i get for example the list of all the attribues (Class : Attribute) in a view,  i can't get the Site of this attribute or its user in the template.

Someone has a suggestion to do that ? thank you

Comment: Why not? You can just return `{{ myattribute.userid }}`, or `{{ myattribute.site }}`.

Comment: yes i can but if i want to get the name of the site or of the user what can i do ?

Comment: `{{ myattribute.userid.name }}`, or `{{ myattribute.site.name }}`.